# vector norm based on a semi-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

While I was reading a paper, I came across the following statement:

> Given a semidefinite matrix $G$ with proper dimensions, the $G$-norm of $x$ is $\|x\|_G = \sqrt{x^TGx}$.

When I tried to check the norm properties, I cannot see why if $\|x\|_G = 0$ implies that $x = 0$. At least, to my understanding, I can find $x \neq 0$ such that $\|x\|_G = 0$.

Comment: If the only hypothesis is that $G$ is semidefinite you cannot prove this. In fact $G$ may be $0$!

Comment: Does the paper claim that a $G$-norm is indeed a norm? Because sometime a name is just a name. It need not to be consistent to established definition.

Comment: @user251257: maybe that explains a bit the confusion I'm having.